# How to give access to Grafana panel on a local network

Tags: prometheus, grafana, remote-access

I have glanced a dozen of videos and websites now to get a simple answer to my question: I have grafana and built a dashboard panel on ubuntu computer. Now I want to access this panel on from another computer on the same network.

I could not find a simple answer to my question. The problem, they all use pure computer terminology, I get lost. I am from non-computers background.

I would appreciate if you could direct me to website or video explaining in simple steps.

Now this is what I tried:

**Step1:** Go to the panel I created on Grafana, select share

[image]

**Step2:** Select link and copy the url at bottom
[image]

**Step3:** This is the url

```
http://10.....:3000/d/0npXo7mgz/new-dashboard?orgId=1&kiosk=&viewPanel=2
```

**Step4:** Go to another computer o the same network and paste this on the browser and the response is:
[image]

My question is: why I am not able to access this on another computer on the same local network?

Comment: Are you running Grafana on localhost?

Comment: @dnnshssm Don't mind, how to check if I am running on localhost or not?

Comment: You will need to learn how networking works. It is not a Grafana issue.

Comment: @JanGaraj I believe I have a basic understanding of networking, not complete networking. Can you elaborate a bit? or Can you list the steps toward my goal as above? or what is wrong with my above steps? Thanks